# How do you allocate an std::array on the heap?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, heap-memory, std

Having a bit of trouble allocating an std::array on the heap.

Here's what I've tried:

```
std::array<int,3> *arr1; 
arr1 = new std::array<int,3>;
arr1[0] = 1;
```

However, the error I get is:

error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::array’).

I've also tried:

```
arr1[0][0] = 1;
```

which works, but so does:

```
arr1[5][5] = 2;
```

which shouldn't work since std::array<int, 3> indicates the array size should be only 3 integers.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `(*arr1)[0] = 1;`

Comment: but if I do that, I can still do: (*arr1)[10] = 1;

Comment: Well, yeah, `std::array`'s `operator[]` does no bounds checking. That has nothing to do with dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax to access the array is `*arr1` and then to index into it e.g. `(*arr1)[1]`.

`arr1[0][1]` is equivalent to that, but harder to understand and any higher first index would be out-of-bounds causing undefined behavior.

`[]` does not do any bounds-checking, so you will not get any warning or error for e.g. `(*arr1)[10]`. If you do this the program will simply have undefined behavior, meaning that you will have no guarantee on how it will behave.

If you want an exception to be thrown when you index out-of-bounds use `arr1->at(10)` instead of `(*arr1)[10]`.

---

A heap-allocated `std::array` is not likely to have significant benefits over just using a `std::vector`, but will cause you extra trouble to manage its lifetime manually.

Simply use `std::vector` instead, which will also allocate the memory for the elements on the heap:

```
std::vector<int> arr1(3);
arr1[0] = 1; // ok
arr1.at(10) = 1; // throws out-of-bounds exception
```